# "Iranian" or "Iranians"?

Tags: plural-forms

From VOA Special English:

> This week, Iranian and international negotiators agreed on first steps to limit Iran's nuclear program.

Should the word "Iranian" be added with a letter "s"(Iranians)? If it refers to the Iranian people, I think the plural form "Iranians" may be appropriate. So why does it use the singular form? Thanks.

Comment: In this case, the word _Iranian_ functions as an adjective, modifying the word _negotiators_. What kind of negotiators agreed? **Iranian negotiators** (international negotiators, too). The sentence is correct as written. If the sentence was parsed differently, though – as in: (Iranians) and (international negotiators) – then you might have caught a misprint.

Answer (score 4):

*Iranian and international* is a coordination of adjectives:

> This week, [ [ Iranian and international ] negotiators ] agreed on first steps to limit Iran's nuclear program.

If you'd like to interpret this as ellipsis, you can:

> This week, [ Iranian **negotiators** and international negotiators ] agreed on first steps to limit Iran's nuclear program.

*Iranian* can be an adjective or a noun, which you can see if you look it up in a dictionary such as [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/iranian).